Has low pressure been generated in the open space of this device?

A represents the left and right speakers, B represents the left and right baffles, C represents the rectangular holes on the left and right baffles through which the sound waves from the speakers can enter the space between the baffles, D represents the scale, and E represents the flat plate placed on the scale.
When a speaker is running, a scale indicates a negative number indicating that a pressure below atmospheric pressure has been generated on the surface of a tablet. Why does this device generate low pressure? What is the principle behind it?
Reference video:
enter link description here

IDK, but I would not trust an electronic scale to read true in a high vibration environment.

Sound is a pressure wave as well.

@JonCuster So how can pressure below atmospheric pressure be generated on a tablet?

The speakers were driven at 60Hz. The wavelength of 60Hz sound in dry air at STP is much greater than the dimensions of that apparatus, so IMO, the best way to describe what the speakers and the baffles do is, they create an oscillating current of air around the slab of wood sitting on the scale. The author claims that the air current lifts the slab. I don't have any opinion about the reasonableness of that claim, but like I said above, I absolutely would not trust that scale to give a meaningful reading in the presence of the 60Hz excitation. That's not how it was meant to be used.

@SolomonSlow https://youtu.be/kG6vXGidQbo?si=dPSMYGMnNzXoj4Ey
https://youtube.com/shorts/R9mExXwv4ME?si=x9g8qY8E-LdTTIJH

Each of those videos shows a completely different apparatus—different from each other, and different from the one in the video that you cited in your original question. If you want opinions about the ones in your comment, immediately above, then those probably should be separate "questions" for this forum.

From the title of my question, what I mean is low pressure, which is low air pressure.
@SolomonSlow  Sorry, the low voltage was just a typo.
The video is of the same type and uses speakers as the equipment. I asked my question because I saw a person posting this type of video and didn't know its principle.
